# jquery - fadeOut callback does not always execute

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, fadeout

A part of my code:

```
        anObject.fadeOut(fadeOutTime, function(){
            anObject.css('display', 'none');
            console.log("inside the callback");
            veryImportantMethod();

        });
```

Ufnortunatelly it seems the callback is not alredy executed. I even tried debugging it and noticed that sometimes it just skis the body of the callback function and jump out... Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that is the case then use `.promise().done()`:

```
anObject.fadeOut(fadeOutTime).promise().done(function(){
        anObject.css('display', 'none');
        console.log("inside the callback");
        veryImportantMethod();
    });
```